# MonoDroid does not support running the previous version

Tags: android

i debug a program in vs2012 and receive this error on emulator:

Could not create the Android package. See the Output (Build) window for more details.
MonoDroid does not support running the previous version.  Please ensure your solution builds before running or debugging it.